# Where are ActiveRecord's comparison and bitwise interfaces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm wondering why Active Record doesn't have a native/baked-in query interface for all bitwise and comparison operators.

I've been using/supporting Rails since 2.3 and sort-of just waiting for it to arrive, but now that Rails 5 is out I feel like I need to ask, are `OR`, `AND`, `gte`, `lte`, etc., and all other bitwise and comparison operators going to be baked into Rails/AR natively?  If not, I'm curious as to why?

Answer (score 3):

**OR** - Rails 5 did introduce `OR` - http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/05/30/rails-5-adds-or-support-in-active-record.html.

**AND** - Isn't `AND` just the chaining of `where` on `ActiveRecord::Relation`?

Other bitwise operators - I agree, there is no wrapper present for them in ActiveRecord yet.

You can check out [`squeel` gem](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel) [[railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/354-squeel?view=asciicast)]. It provides a nice API to do these operations.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `OR` before, I didn't see any rails docs for it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [AREL](https://github.com/rails/arel) directly. It provides support for bitwise operators, among a whole raftload of other powerful things. In some ways the syntax is a tiny bit more arcane than straight ActiveRecord::Relation building syntax, but the additional granularity of control you get is well worth the complexity.

Here is a quick example (taken straight from the documentation) of how you can use a bitwise operator with AREL:

```
users = Arel::Table.new(:users)
users.where((users[:bitmap] & 16).gt(0)).project(Arel.sql('*'))
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.  I do know about arel, and I'm sure its great, however I'm more curious why bitwise etc., isn't baked into rails.

Comment: ah. well, my suspicion, not being involved in the development of the framework, is that because AREL is designed to provide finer grained interactions with the database, there might have been a decision to keep the basic ActiveRecord interfaces simpler. AREL is what ActiveRecord is built upon (not an external gem) so one could argue that these operators are baked into rails. just not where you were looking for them.